# Access TextField from another class or method without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Okay, this might be one of the most basic questions ever, but all answers I find use storyboard to declare an outlet for a label, textfield or whatever element that needs to be changed. I, however, don't use storyboards and write everything in code. Now I have a function setupViews, where I define a textfield:

```
let usernameInput = UITextField()
```

Now, I can perfectly set the text or placeholder or whatever inside this setupViews() class, but how can I access it outside? For example, if I have a function logIn(), I want to call usernameInput.text and use it in this function.

Someone who can point me in the right direction? Do I need to declare this textfield globally, in another file, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create my views in code I always associate a property with the view that has all those various display values.

I have not tested this code to see but hopefully the following will give you an idea.

```
import UIKit 

struct {
    var name: String
}

class CustomViewController : UIViewController {
    // some struct which contains data for view
    var customViewData : ViewDataInfo? {
        didSet {
            labelOnScreen.text = customViewData.name
        }
    }

    var labelOnScreen: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.text = "Placeholder information..."

        // stuff auto layout 
        label.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        view.addSubview(label)

        // set your constraints here
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Gosh. I knew it had to be something pretty simple, I just couldn't figure it out. Makes so much more sense now. Thank you, sir.